# Check for leading zero in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with values for username column like `07562`.
I would like to check for columns that don't contains `leading zero` like `7562` and delete them.
I'm doing it this way, but this pass if there is a zero somewhere in the username

```py
df['username'] = df['username'].where(df['username'].str.contains("0")) # pass if 75602 :(
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: use `.str.startswith('0')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easiest this way:

```
df = df[df['username'].str.startswith("0"))]
```

You just need to filter the dataframe based on username, would not need to create and drop NA too.